# What is the proper way to fetch items from a custom db table and output them in twig?

Tags: plugin-development

My main issue is perhaps not totally understanding the unique idioms of Yii, but I need to output data from my custom data tables in a template. So obviously I have a `MyPluginVariables` class and a `MyPluginService` to handle to actual business logic.

Using my `MyPlugin_FooRecord` I can use ActiveRecord to fetch some data. But this obviously returns the actual record objects, when I really just need a model passed to the template. From what I understand, I should use models not the records themselves. Is this correct?

Also, how exactly should I build a chainable syntax, similar to fetching entries in a template?

For example, I am trying to get this to work:

```
{% set rows = craft.myPlugin.someMethod().limit(10).order('some_col').sort('asc') %}
```

So relating this syntax back to my original question, how would I build this and return an array of models? The `ElementCriteriaModel` will automatically execute the `find()` method when it's used an array, should I just overriding the `__toArray()` method?

I have been searching and looking through the docs, so perhaps I missed something. I have also been looking through the code in Craft, but due to the abstractions and not being familiar with Yii core classes, I am getting a little lost in figuring out how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure almost all of this stuff out by diving through the code. The only exception is triggering the `find()` method automatically.

The key here was to follow the code in the `ElementCriteriaModel`. First thing I did was create a method in the `MyPluginService` class to fetch the data.

```
public function foo($criteria = false)
{
    return new MyPlugin_MyCriteriaModel($criteria ?: array());
}
```

I added a wrapper to my `MyPluginVariable` class.

```
public function parcels($criteria = array())
{
    return craft()->myPlugin->foo($criteria);
}
```

This will allow for the following syntax:

```
{% set data = craft.myPlugin.foo().limit(5).offset(1).find() %}
```

You must define a `find()` method in your `MyPlugin_MyCriteriaModel` class that will perform the SQL query to actually fetch your data. You also have to loop through the results set and instantiate `MyPlugin_FooModel` for each db row if you want to return a `Model` to the template instead of a `stdObject` or array.

For example, my find method looks like this:

```
public function find($attributes = null)
{   
    $this->setAttributes($attributes);

    if (!isset($this->_matchedObjects))
    {
        $objects = craft()->myplugin_foo->find($this);

        $this->setMatchedObjects($objects);
    }

    return $this->_matchedObjects;
}
```

Then in `MyPlugin_FooService` I have this:

```
public function query(MyPlugin_MyCriteriaModel $criteria)
{
    $record = new MyPlugin_FooRecord();

    $query = craft()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from($record->getTableName())
        ->limit($criteria->limit)
        ->offset($criteria->offset)
        ->order($criteria->order);

    if($criteria->id)
    {
        $query->where('id = :id', array(':id' => $criteria->id));
    }

    if($criteria->uid)
    {
        $query->where('uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $criteria->uid));
    }

    // More conditionals may go here

    return $query;
}

public function find(MyPlugin_MyCriteriaModel $criteria)
{
    $query = $this->query($criteria);

    return $this->_populateModelsFromArray($query->queryAll());
}

protected function _populateModelsFromArray(Array $array)
{
    $models = array();

    foreach($array as $row)
    {
        $models[] = MyPlugin_FooModel::populateModel($row);
    }

    return $models;
}
```

Comment: what does your MyPluginVariable class look like with the wrapper function?

Comment: also are you extending ElementCriteriaModel in MyPlugin_MyCriteriaModel?

Comment: `MyPlugin_MyCriteriaModel` is a class that extends `BaseModel`. It's just a regular model with some arbitrary attributes. I did base the logic off `ElementCriteriaModel`, but it does not extend it. The `MyPluginVariable` wrapping method looks like this: `public function parcels($criteria = array()) { return craft()->postmaster->parcels($criteria); }`

Comment: so where your calling foo above, for your plugin your calling parcels?

Comment: That's right. The logic is kinda confusing. You use the variables to call the criteria model, which returns a "chainable" object. Then the `find` method in the criteria model sends the model to the `ParcelService` instance, which actually runs the query.

Comment: Feel free to download Postmaster to see the complete code I am referencing. https://github.com/objectivehtml/Postmaster-for-Craft-CMS